# Check in header if 'thank you' page - Opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

In OpenCart 2, I am editing the appearance/php of the header only in the "success"/"thank you" page (catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/success.tpl).

So, in catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl I want to do something like:

```
if( $is_thank_you_page ){
   echo "stuff";
   // bonus: I wanted to get the order email but maybe it should be a different post
}
```

But how can I check in the `header.tpl` if it is the "success"/"thank you" page?

I tried setting a variable in `success.tpl` before printing the header with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (go about it based on your URL):

```
<?php 
$parameters = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(end($parameters) === 'success.tpl'){ 
    //the condition with $parameters depends on the exact look of your URL
    //you could also access an index directly
}
```

Basically, it takes the REQUEST_URI (part after the domain), splits it around the / symbols and then checks if it ends with success.tpl

You could also make a `switch` for the `end($parameters)` instead of the `if`.

Comment: That helped me think about the UTMs which I ended up using. Thank you for the help and idea!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know opencart structure, but if this value never change you can try with strpos/stripos, something like:

```
if(stripos($var_with_page_title, 'thank you') !== false) {
    do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you detect checkout/success page in you header, do following:

open **catalog/controller/common/header.php**

find

```
// Menu
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
```

Add before

```
// success page checking 
$data['success'] = '';
if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'checkout/success') {
  $data['success'] = true;
}

// looking for email from the order
$data['success_email'] = '';
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
  $data['success_email'] = $customer_info['email'];
} elseif (isset(this->session->data['guest']['email'])) {
  $data['success_email'] = $this->session->data['guest']['email'];
}
```

Now in **catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/common/header.tpl**

add anywhere you like

```
<?php if ($success) { ?>
  //do something
  <?php if ($success_email) { ?><?php echo $success_email; ?><?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

With *bonus email*

Comment: No, unfortunately neither works. I understand that I need to set the variables in the form of `$data['foo']` but maybe the email is cleared from the session by that time. Then again I do not know why `$data['success']` is not passed

Comment: Have you cleared OCMOD cache? Email is clearing from session by the time, but not just after checkout. I will test it again tomorrow and update the answer. Keep in touch. $data['success'] should work, already checked it